# Prism.Forms NavigationService with Pages loaded from xaml

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, prism

I'm trying to load pages from xaml files and then push them to the navigation stack of prism. For this purpose I added the following methods to my NavigationService:

```
public class MyNavigationService : PageNavigationService, IMyNavigationService
{
    public async Task<INavigationResult> NavigateAsync(Page page, INavigationParameters parameters, bool? useModalNavigation, bool animated)
    {
        var result = new NavigationResult();
        try
        {
            NavigationSource = PageNavigationSource.NavigationService;

            await ProcessNavigation(GetCurrentPage(), page, parameters, useModalNavigation, animated);
            result.Success = true;
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Log(ex.ToString(), Category.Exception, Priority.High);
            result.Exception = ex;
            return result;
        }
        finally
        {
            NavigationSource = PageNavigationSource.Device;
        }
    }

    protected virtual async Task ProcessNavigation(Page currentPage, Page nextPage, INavigationParameters parameters, bool? useModalNavigation, bool animated)
    {
        if (nextPage == null)
            return;

        if (currentPage == null)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
            //await ProcessNavigationForRootPage(nextPage, parameters, useModalNavigation, animated);
            return;
        }

        if (currentPage is ContentPage)
        {
            await ProcessNavigationForContentPage(currentPage, nextPage, parameters, useModalNavigation, animated);
        }
        else if (currentPage is NavigationPage)
        {
            //await ProcessNavigationForNavigationPage((NavigationPage)currentPage, nextPage, parameters, useModalNavigation, animated);
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        else if (currentPage is TabbedPage)
        {
            //await ProcessNavigationForTabbedPage((TabbedPage)currentPage, nextPage, parameters, useModalNavigation, animated);
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        else if (currentPage is CarouselPage)
        {
            //await ProcessNavigationForCarouselPage((CarouselPage)currentPage, nextPage, parameters, useModalNavigation, animated);
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        else if (currentPage is MasterDetailPage)
        {
            //await ProcessNavigationForMasterDetailPage((MasterDetailPage)currentPage, nextPage, parameters, useModalNavigation, animated);
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Processes a navigation for a content page.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="currentPage">The current page.</param>
    /// <param name="nextPage">The page to navigate to.</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">Navigation parameters</param>
    /// <param name="useModalNavigation">If <c>true</c> uses PopModalAsync, if <c>false</c> uses PopAsync.</param>
    /// <param name="animated">If <c>true</c> the transition is animated, if <c>false</c> there is no animation on transition.</param>
    /// <returns>Navigation task</returns>
    protected virtual async Task ProcessNavigationForContentPage(Page currentPage, Page nextPage, INavigationParameters parameters, bool? useModalNavigation, bool animated)
    {
        await ProcessNavigation(nextPage, new Queue<string>(), parameters, useModalNavigation, animated);

        await DoNavigateAction(currentPage, string.Empty, nextPage, parameters, async () =>
        {
            await DoPush(currentPage, nextPage, useModalNavigation, animated);
        });
    }
}
```

The navigation for this pages works and displays correctly.
But when I try to navigate further (via `navigationService.NavigateAsync("ViewName");`) it does nothing, even though the `NavigationResult.Success` is true. The page "ViewName" is a registered ContentPage (registered via `container.Register< ViewName, ViewNameViewModel >()`).

I think that my navigation with pages, as seen above, is missing something important for navigating further.

Has someone done something similar and could help me?

**EDIT:**
I noticed that if I want to navigate away from my xaml loaded page, somehow the `GetCurrentPage()` method and the loacal field _page returns a Page with everything set to null instead of the page I did load from the xaml.

Comment: why do you need to create your own Navigation service?
The point of using MVVM library is to save you the time of doing this and other tasks in ViewModelBase

Comment: Navigation is very easy and smart in a unique way in Prism. I have completed almost all navigation scenarios such as MasterDetail, TabbedPage, ModelNavigation and others with ease. share you scenario if you require any specific naviagtion.

Comment: I started extending the prism NavigationService because I could not find a way of navigating to pages i created from xaml at runtime. With the prism NavigationService you have to register every view type which is not possible in my case, is it?

Comment: If you read the ReadmMe in github for Xamarin Forms Prism:

"Prism is a framework for building loosely coupled, maintainable, and testable XAML applications in WPF, Windows 10 UWP, and Xamarin Forms." Keyword here is XAML

Comment: "Prism provides an implementation of a collection of design patterns that are helpful in writing well-structured and maintainable XAML applications"
https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism

Comment: Prism is encourging you to focus on XAML and not use the code behind. I am not sure actually if you can create pages from code, register them, and navigate to them at runtime.

Comment: I didn't need to use the code behind since you can use lists for bindable content other bindable components with visiblity and other tricks

Comment: I do not use code behinde files (xaml.cs). I'm using the xamarin method: `var page = new ContentPage().LoadFromXaml("<ContenPage>....</ContentPage>");` The string is the content of a .xaml file. After that page is initialized I want to navigate to it. But prism only allows you to navigate via name of a registered page. So I somehow have to register my loaded xaml page at run time.